# How to construct the Bode plot of an FIR filter when coefficients are badly conditioned?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to plot the Bode plot of an FIR filter which is used to reject unwanted frequencies over 100 Hz with a sampling frequency of 500kHz. The filter has many coefficients in order to produce as much cleaner output as possible but the error message when trying to construct the Bode plot refers   to badly conditioned coefficients.

I tryied to reduce the number of coefficients from 100000 to 2000 (numtaps_2 in the code below) but this also didn't work and I got the same error message.

Error message :
/home/goodvibrations/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/signal/_filter_design.py:1709: BadCoefficients: Badly conditioned filter coefficients (numerator): the results may be meaningless
warnings.warn("Badly conditioned filter coefficients (numerator): the "
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py:779: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
y = y * x + pv
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py:779: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
y = y * x + pv
/home/goodvibrations/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/signal/_filter_design.py:188: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
h = polyval(b, s) / polyval(a, s)

---

```
#Code example of what I'm trying to do

#FIR Low-pass filter on the signal with the inverter connected and off

#The length of the filter(number of coefficients, the filter order + 1)
numtaps_2 = 100000
fs = 500000
cutoff_hz = 0.00001
nyq_rate = fs/2 


#Use of firwin to create low-pass FIR filter
fir_co = signal.firwin(numtaps_2, cutoff_hz)
w_fir_co, h_fir_co = signal.freqz(fir_co, [1])


sys = signal.TransferFunction(w_fir_co, h_fir_co)

w, mag, phase = signal.bode(sys)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for the question above is that when a large FIR filter is constructed the signal.freqz() function has a lot of error and the FFT approach is recommend.

Notes

---

Using Matplotlib's :func:`matplotlib.pyplot.plot` function as the callable
for `plot` produces unexpected results, as this plots the real part of the complex transfer function, not the magnitude.

Try `lambda w, h: plot(w, np.abs(h))`.

A direct computation via (R)FFT is used to compute the frequency response when the following conditions are met:

1. An integer value is given for `worN`.
2. `worN` is fast to compute via FFT (i.e.,`next_fast_len(worN) <scipy.fftpack.next_fast_len>` equals `worN`).
3. The denominator coefficients are a single value (`a.shape[0] == 1`).
4. `worN` is at least as long as the numerator coefficients (`worN >= b.shape[0]`).
5. If `b.ndim > 1`, then `b.shape[-1] == 1`.

For long FIR filters, the FFT approach can have lower error and be much faster than the equivalent direct polynomial calculation.

source :

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.2.1/scipy/signal/filter_design.py#L34-L36